# Parse nested markdown list with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, markdown

I want to parse some nested markdwon lists, like below:

```
* elem 1
* elem 2
  * child 1
  * child 2
    * child 1
* elem 3
  * child 1
```

The list nesting are tabbed. So each level has *n* tabs.
I'm searching for a regex which can give me each level, e.g. Level 3 has `\t\t`, Level 2 has only `\t`, Level 1 has no tab, but all starting with `*`.

How can I match theses requires with different regexp?

One try for the Level 1 elements was:

```
^(?=\*).*
```

But this selects only the first element of Level 1 (e.g. elem 2 and elem 3 are not found).

BR,

mybecks

Comment: Have you tried the global modifier? `/^(?=\*).*/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that returns a regexp (based on yours) for matching all the elements on a certain level:

```
function getNestedRegexp(level) {
  return new RegExp('^(?=\\t{'+level+'}\\*).*','gm');
}

// Usage:
var elements = str.match(getNestedRegexp(1)); // all elements on level 1
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/EcAKIza/1/edit

As others have mentioned, regexp may not be the best solution here, so be careful if you pick this option.

EDIT: I am not sure why you are using a positive lookahead there. A better regexp could be:

```
/^\t{N}\*.*/gm
```

DEMO & EXPLANATION: http://regex101.com/r/rZ7mD1

Comment: Thank you, `/^\t{N}\*.*/gm` did it. Great site and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use:

```
/^\s+\* (.+)$/gm
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
/^\*.*?(?=^\*|\Z)/sm
```

Basically it means match from beginning of line, match literally `*` then anything non-greedily up to the but not including the next `^\*` or `EOF`

EDIT:

This wont work for you, as javascript doesn't support `\Z`, oops had the wrong regex engine flavour enabled, will update shortly :)

EDIT 2:

This should work in javascript:

```
^\*[^]+?(?=^\*)|^\*[^]+
```

Had to use an alternation for the very last element ie if you remove `|^\*[^]+` from the end of the regex it wont match the last element :(.